# C# recursion issue, ++ parameter doesn't adds 1 when int is = to 5

Tags: recursion

Why "K" can't get higher than 5? Output starts from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and loops to 5.

```
class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int k = 0;

            loop1(k);

        }

        static void loop1 (int k)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k);

            k++;

            while (k <= 5)
            {
                loop1(k);
            }

        }
    }
```

[image: console output]

Comment: You must use a conditional instead of a loop like `while`, replace it with an `if`.

Comment: ty. If works fine, but i cant understand what is a problem with "while" "do while".

Comment: I'd try to explain the issues further on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the rules for recursion is the break condition. And in your code there is none since you are using the `while` loop. Replace it with an `if` and your code will no longer loop till the infinite.

Another rule is to get closer to the goal. Since you want to display a number higher than 5 and *after* that stop, you need to increase the value of `k` *after* the conditional.

Modified version of the recursive function:

```
static void loop1 (int k)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k);

    if (k <= 5)
    {
        loop1(++k);
    }

}
```

The expected results will be as follow: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`